# python module not properly installed without apparent reason

Tags: python, pip

I want to create a Docker image for a package that provides a CLI tool.
My image works if I install the package from our pypi server but it doesn't work if I install it from source.
Installing from source is required to enable the developer to test his code in a container before publishing a new release.

```
# Building is done using
# docker build . --build-arg PIPCONTENT="`cat ~/.pip/pip.conf | base64 `" -t tmw:latest
#
FROM python:3.6-slim as base

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# this is our first build stage, it will not persist in the final image
FROM base as intermediate

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## contains credentials
ARG PIPCONTENT
RUN mkdir -p /root/.pip/ && echo ${PIPCONTENT}  | base64 -d > /root/.pip/pip.conf

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY setup.py MANIFEST.in tagger_model_workbench /app/

# doesn't create /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagger_model_workbench
#RUN python setup.py sdist
#RUN pip install dist/*.tar.gz

# TeamCity: python setup.py sdist && twine upload --verbose -r pypicloud dist/*
# does create /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tagger_model_workbench
RUN pip install tagger-model-workbench

# build final image
#FROM base

#COPY --from=intermediate /usr/local /usr/local

EXPOSE 8050
ENTRYPOINT ["tagger-model-workbench", "0.0.0.0", "8050"]
```

Here is the setup.py:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def get_install_requires():
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "requirements.txt")) as f:
        return [line for line in map(str.strip, f) if line and not line.startswith('-') and not line.startswith("git+")]


setup(
    name='tagger_model_workbench',
    version='0.2.4',
    packages=find_packages(include=("tagger_model_workbench", "tagger_model_workbench.*",)),
    url='',
    license='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description='',
    install_requires=get_install_requires(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['tagger-model-workbench=tagger_model_workbench.app.main:main'],
    }
)
```

Running the container with the `python setup.py sdist && pip install dist/*.tar.gz` option causes this error message:

```
tmw_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
tmw_1  |   File "/usr/local/bin/tagger-model-workbench", line 6, in <module>
tmw_1  |     from tagger_model_workbench.app.main import main
tmw_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tagger_model_workbench'
```

Installation using `pip install` properly installs the package from our internal pypi whereas building and installing using built artifact doesn't.
Build commands are identical. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `tagger_model_workbench` is the folder with the source code of the module. If you copy it in the way you described above it will only copy the content of your folder, but not the folder. Depending on your `setup.py` this can lead to an module without any python files if you referencing the folder in your `packages` list in the `setup.py` instead of listing the content of the folder. If the module have no python files in it you will get the described error message.

If my assumption that `tagger_model_workbench` is a folder is right you can simple fix it. Just make sure you are adding the complete folder to the docker image. Simply adapt the line where you copy the `setup.py` in the following way:

```
COPY setup.py MANIFEST.in /app/
COPY tagger_model_workbench /app/tagger_model_workbench
```

Comment: Do you know how I can keep this all in one line? I'd rather not have to create an additional `COPY` per directory I want to have in my container...

Comment: Sure simply create a folder with all files and folders you want to add to the docker image and use this folder for the copy command. For your case a folder for example call it app and put all you files and folders you want to have in your docker image in that folder than you can call `COPY app ./app/`